# get the length of an array with unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays

so I have an array containing some objects. I want to compare these objects with each other. If the `fromId` **AND** the `toId` properties are the same, it is an duplicate.

Example:

```js
const data = [{
  fromId: 1,
  toId: 2,
  finished: true
}, {
  fromId: 1,
  toId: 2,
  finished: false
}, {
  fromId: 5,
  toId: 9,
  finished: false
}, {
  fromId: 1,
  toId: 5,
  finished: true
}, {
  fromId: 2,
  toId: 1,
  finished: false
}];

$(document).ready(() => {
  const duplicates = data.filter(x =>
    data
    .filter(y => y.fromId == x.fromId && y.toId == x.toId)
    .length > 1
  );

  console.log(duplicates);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And I want to get the length of this data array but only with unique values. I tried to remove all duplicate values and found a solution here

> [Get all non-unique values (i.e.: duplicate/more than one occurrence) in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/get-all-non-unique-values-i-e-duplicate-more-than-one-occurrence-in-an-array)

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8, 2, 9, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];

$(document).ready(() => {
  const uniqueValues = data.filter((connection, index) => data.indexOf(connection) == index);

  console.log(uniqueValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but on this solution I just use `indexOf` for the whole object. How can I compare the `fromId` and `toId` and remove the duplicate on same matches?

From the original array I would remove one

```
{
      fromId: 1,
      toId: 2,
      finished: false
    }
```

because the `fromId` and `toId` exist already at another object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `filter` nested in another `filter` (bad runtime complexity), since you're just looking for the length of the resulting unique array, you might instead combine each `fromId` and `toId` into a string, put that string into a `Set` (which only retains unique values), and then check that `Set`'s size:

```js
const data=[{fromId:1,toId:2,finished:!0},{fromId:1,toId:2,finished:!1},{fromId:5,toId:9,finished:!1},{fromId:1,toId:5,finished:!0},{fromId:2,toId:1,finished:!1}];

const idSet = new Set(data.map(({ fromId, toId }) => fromId + '_' + toId));
console.log(idSet.size);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to filter the array with unique objects and then get the length value together with the unique array:

```js
const data = [{
  fromId: 1,
  toId: 2,
  finished: true
}, {
  fromId: 1,
  toId: 2,
  finished: false
}, {
  fromId: 5,
  toId: 9,
  finished: false
}, {
  fromId: 1,
  toId: 5,
  finished: true
}, {
  fromId: 2,
  toId: 1,
  finished: false
}];

$(document).ready(() => {
  var uniqueArray = data.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
    var existObj = acc.find(item => item.fromId === obj.fromId && item.toId === obj.toId);
    if(existObj){
      return acc;
    }
    acc.push(obj);
    return acc;
  },[]);
console.log('unique array ', uniqueArray);
console.log('length of unique object ', uniqueArray.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **new array**, and push the lements only once, checking if they already exists or not using **inArray** function from jQuery:

```js
const data = [{
  fromId: 1,
  toId: 2,
  finished: true
}, {
  fromId: 1,
  toId: 2,
  finished: false
}, {
  fromId: 5,
  toId: 9,
  finished: false
}, {
  fromId: 1,
  toId: 5,
  finished: true
}, {
  fromId: 2,
  toId: 1,
  finished: false
}];

$(document).ready(() => {
   
  var filtered = [];
  $.each(data, function(i, item){
      if($.inArray(item, filtered) === -1){
        filtered.push(item);
      }
      
      
  });
  console.log(filtered.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery [inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Answer (score 0):

While CertainPerformance's answer is probably better for your scenario, the `indexOf` alternative that does not compare item identities would be `findIndex`. However, this is ES6+ only, but most modern browsers implement it (sorry, no IE11).

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with a simple forEach - this is plain JS and not ES5/6 or jQuery

```js
const data = [{fromId: 1,toId: 2,finished: true},{fromId: 1,toId: 2,finished: false}, {fromId: 5,toId: 9,finished: false}, {fromId: 1,toId: 5,finished: true}, {fromId: 2, toId: 1, finished: false }];
var combos = [];
var  dupes = [];
var unique = [];

data.forEach(function(item){
  var combo = ""+item.fromId+"."+item.toId;
  if (combos.indexOf(combo) == -1) {
    combos.push(combo);
    unique.push(item);
  }
  else {
    dupes.push(item);
  }
});
console.log("dupes",dupes);
console.log("unique",unique,unique.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, many options available... Will give you another one with `lodash/fp`:

Assuming you have:

```
import {flow, map, uniq} from 'lodash/fp'
```

Do this:

```
const count = flow(
    map(o => o.fromId + '.' + o.toId),
    uniq,
  )(data).length

console.log('Count: ', count)
```